# Создать новую страницу в DomPdf

Tags: dompdf, php

Добрый день.

Как в DomPdf создать новую страницу?

Везде примеры - вставляем html  и генерируем, 
а мне надо вставить html ->новая страница->вставить html2 -> сгенерировать.

Как это сделать? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В том месте, где нужен разрыв, довабляю

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
```